# ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.modpython

Tags: django

Django was installed via apt-ger on Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install python-django
```

Need development version for new features.

Removed previous installation via

```
sudo apt-get purge python-django
```

Re-installed Django following this article

http://jeffbaier.com/articles/installing-django-on-an-ubuntu-linux-server/

```
django-admin.py --version
1.3 pre-alpha SVN-13591
```

Have not made any changes to httpd.conf file

Getting this error

```
MOD_PYTHON ERROR

PathInfo:       ''

Phase:          'PythonHandler'
Handler:        'django.core.handlers.modpython'

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1537, in HandlerDispatch
    default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1202, in _process_target
    module = import_module(module_name, path=path)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 304, in import_module
    return __import__(module_name, {}, {}, ['*'])

ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.modpython
```

Few tests

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> import django.core.handlers.modpython 
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked in django directory

```
 python setup.py install
```